# Prove that 2007 can't be written as a sum of 3 cubes

Tags: number-theory

As the question says, prove that 2007 can't be written as a sum of cubes of 3 natural numbers.

Comment: I suppose, brute force is not allowed.

Comment: @Peter If it isn't then, unless you already know a priori a solution or you are Ramanujan, I'm not sure there's a definite way to follow: it is an open question whether all naturals $\;\neq\pm4\pmod9\;$ are expressable as the sum of three cubes...and this is so even for rather small natural numbers (say, $\;33,42\;$ , for example) . Perhaps knowing that $\;2007=9\cdot223\;$ helps somehow...I don't know.

Comment: The natural numbers must be less than 13, for what it's worth.

Comment: @DonAntonio Or maybe finding $2007=14^3-2^3-9^3$ helps somehow... Don't know, either.

Comment: maybe using digital roots help rule out a few cases, but it's still tedious...

Comment: @DonAntonio: $-2$ and $-9$ are not natural numbers, whether one includes $0$ or not.

Answer (score 7):

Since you're restricted to the natural numbers we only need to check cubes of numbers between $1$ and $12$, because $13^3 > 2007$.

If the largest of the three is $12^3 = 1728$ then show that you can't pick a pair of numbers from $1,8,27,64,125,216$ such that the sum of these numbers is $2007-1728 = 279$.  Only $216+216$, $216+125$, and $216+64$ are greater than $279$; all other pairs are less ($125+125 = 250 < 279$).

If the largest is $11^3 = 1331$, then check pairs drawn from $1,8,27,64,125,216,343,512$ for a sum of $2007 - 1331 = 676$.  Only $512+512$ down to $512 + 216$, and $343+343$ are greater than $676$; all other pairs are less than $676$.

If the largest is $10^3 = 1000$, then check pairs drawn from $1,8,27,64,125,216,343,512,729,1000$ for a sum of $1007$.  $1000+1000$ down to $1000 + 8$, $729 + 729$ down to $729 + 343$, and $512 + 512$ are greater than $1007$; all others are less.

If the largest is $9^3 = 729$, then check pairs drawn from $1,8,27,64,125,216,343,512,729$ for a sum of $1278$.  Only $729 + 729$ is greater than $1278$; all others are less.

Having done that, you're done, because $3 \cdot 8^3 < 2007$.

Comment: Though there is nothing wrong with your answer, checking in this way is no better than what my code does.  You just go down every branch of the tree of finite possibilities showing none work.  My code does the same thing just a little bit less smartly.

Comment: You could shorten the analysis in each case by noting, for example that one of the two cubes summing to $279$ must be larger than $279/2\gt125$, so could only be $216$ (but $279-216=63$ is not a cube).

Answer (score 1):

Proof by exhaustion:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# prove that 2007 can't be written as a sum of cubes of 3 natural numbers

use strict;
use warnings;

# 12^3 < 2007 and 13^3 > 2007 so limit is 12

my $lim = 12;
my $goal = 2007;

my $mindelta = $goal + 1;

# Sums are commutative so we'll do these in order from a <= b <= c <= lim
for (my $a = 0; $a <= $lim; $a++) {
    for (my $b = $a; $b <= $lim; $b++) {
        for (my $c = $b; $c <= $lim; $c++) {
            my $sum = $a ** 3 + $b ** 3 + $c ** 3;
            my $delta = $goal - $sum;

            if (abs($delta) < abs($mindelta)) {
                $mindelta = $delta;

                warn sprintf('Got new best delta %d with' .
                             ' %d^3 + %d^3 + %d^3 = %d',
                             $delta, $a, $b, $c, $sum), "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
$ ./cubes_sum.pl 
Got new best delta 2007 with 0^3 + 0^3 + 0^3 = 0
Got new best delta 2006 with 0^3 + 0^3 + 1^3 = 1
Got new best delta 1999 with 0^3 + 0^3 + 2^3 = 8
Got new best delta 1980 with 0^3 + 0^3 + 3^3 = 27
Got new best delta 1943 with 0^3 + 0^3 + 4^3 = 64
Got new best delta 1882 with 0^3 + 0^3 + 5^3 = 125
Got new best delta 1791 with 0^3 + 0^3 + 6^3 = 216
Got new best delta 1664 with 0^3 + 0^3 + 7^3 = 343
Got new best delta 1495 with 0^3 + 0^3 + 8^3 = 512
Got new best delta 1278 with 0^3 + 0^3 + 9^3 = 729
Got new best delta 1007 with 0^3 + 0^3 + 10^3 = 1000
Got new best delta 676 with 0^3 + 0^3 + 11^3 = 1331
Got new best delta 279 with 0^3 + 0^3 + 12^3 = 1728
Got new best delta 278 with 0^3 + 1^3 + 12^3 = 1729
Got new best delta 271 with 0^3 + 2^3 + 12^3 = 1736
Got new best delta 252 with 0^3 + 3^3 + 12^3 = 1755
Got new best delta 215 with 0^3 + 4^3 + 12^3 = 1792
Got new best delta 154 with 0^3 + 5^3 + 12^3 = 1853
Got new best delta 63 with 0^3 + 6^3 + 12^3 = 1944
Got new best delta -53 with 0^3 + 9^3 + 11^3 = 2060
Got new best delta 7 with 0^3 + 10^3 + 10^3 = 2000
Got new best delta 6 with 1^3 + 10^3 + 10^3 = 2001
Got new best delta -1 with 2^3 + 10^3 + 10^3 = 2008
```

So the closest you can get to 2007 is 2^3 + 10^3 + 10^3 = 2008

Comment: First, using computers to answer mathematical problems can be unacceptable. Second, you seem to have assumed the three cubed integers must be positive...\

Comment: @DonAntonio The assumption that the numbers are positive is valid because the question says  "natural numbers".  Though I guess that means I should have excluded zero.

Comment: That's right, @Brandon...

Comment: You do have too $2008=4^3+6^3+12^3$

Comment: @Piquito yeah the code just reports the first next-best minimum delta that it finds.  When I change the < to <= I get `Got new best delta -1 with 4^3 + 6^3 + 12^3 = 2008`

Comment: while technically a correct proof, I have downvoted this answer -- I consider computer proofs by exhaustion not to be in the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-We use the prime field $\Bbb F_7$ for which the cubes are only $\{1,6,0\}$, in fact:
 $$\Bbb F_7=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,0\}\\\Bbb F_7^3=\{1,1,6,1,6,6,0\}$$ Hence if $2007=x^3+y^3+z^3$ in natural numbers then, because of $2007\equiv5\pmod7$, we have in the field $\Bbb F_7$ the following six possibilities:
$$\{x,y,z\}\in\big\{\{3,3,0\},\{5,5,0\},\{6,6,0\},\{3,5,0\},\{3,6,0\},\{5,6,0\}\big\}$$
Furthermore $12^3\lt 2007\lt 13^3$ so, for example with $\{x,y,z\}=\{3,3,0\}$ we must have, 
$$\begin{cases}x=3+7m_1\\y=3+7m_2\\z=7m_3\end{cases}\Rightarrow\{x,y,z\}=\{10,10,7\},\{10,3,7\},\{3,3,7\}$$ The three possibilities are discarded by hand.

Similarly we can discard  the other five cases $\{5,5,0\},\{6,6,0\},\{3,5,0\},\{3,6,0\},\{5,6,0\}$

Answer (score 0):

We will take some modulos to find that there's no combination that will work for the number $2007$.

First, note that $2007$ is an odd number, so that either there must be exactly one or all three odd cubes. Note: $2007 \equiv 7 mod 8$. When you take all the cubes less than $13$, exactly one is $7 mod 8$, namely $7^3$. We can check all of the $\{3, 3, 1\}, \{5, 1, 1\}, \{5, 5, 5\}$ modulus combinations (see appendix), and they all fail; we must have one of the cubes be $7^3 = 343$.

Now we must find two more cubes that sum to $1664$. We see that $1664 \equiv 0 mod 2$. We can do brute force here, but it's much easier among pairs; we only need to compare $2^3, 4^3, 6^3, 8^3, 10^3$ between themselves, and $1^3, 3^3, 5^3, 7^3, 9^3, 11^3$ among themselves in order to add to an even $1664$. Using @John's observation that $3\cdot 8^3 < 2007$, we needn't bother after we've checked $9^3, 10^3, 11^3$ ($12^3$ is too large).

---

*Appendix*: Computations done:

$[1,\ldots,12]^3 = [1,
8,
27,
64,
125,
216,
343,
512,
729,
1000,
1331,
1728]$

$[1,\ldots,12]^3 mod 8 = [1,
0,
3,
0,
5,
0,
7,
0,
1,
0,
3,
0]$

$1331 + 1331 + [x]_1 > 2007$

$1331 + 729 + [x]_3 > 2007$

$1331 + 125 + [x]_1 < 2007$

$729 + 729 + 125 < 2007$

$125 + 125 + 125 < 2007$

$1664 - 1000 = 664 \neq x^3$

$1664 - 1331 = 333 \neq x^3$

$1664 - 729 = 935 \neq x^3$